# Chua's circuit's pattern not fully shown

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, oscilloscope, software, troubleshooting

I have made a Chua's circuit, and hooked a soundcard oscilloscope to it, to measure the voltage across C1 and C2.

Circuit diagram:[image]
Source:[Kennedy 92(pdf)](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e385/fbd99486bc436f472c53ce12d1f69367c103.pdf).

Software used: soundcard scope.[image]

The soundcard seems to only support mono input, so I have to log data of p.d. across C1 and C2 separately (Using the "log data" option in the software). I then plot them one against another in excel.

Plot:

[image]

A small part of data:

[image]

As you can see, the "double scroll" pattern is not clear. If you look at the data, you can see the left column (p.d. across C1) jumps between around 0.12 and 0.18 all the way.

**Questions: Is the experiment successful?** Is the plot above showing a double scroll? How can I make the double scroll more clear?

Also: I recorded data for at least 20 seconds, but only ended up with 100 data points. I am sure that a soundcard can record something like 40000 data points per second. What's wrong? What other software can turn wave files(.wav) into a *.csv* file so that I can plot using excel?

**Note: both columns of data are with the heading "Channel 1 App" in the log file.**

Comment: What software are you using? When I Google the phrase "soundcard scope" I get something that appears to be different from what you are using. (It also looks like it might be a lot better -- check it out.) Also if you can only sample one signal at a time, then how do you know how to line up your X samples versus your Y samples?

Comment: I recommended you use a soundcard scope to see if it is oscillating at all.  You should see a clear oscillation on a single channel.  Sound cards are AC coupled, so you probably can't see the shift in mid points with it.  As for mono, either your sound only has a single input (microphone) or a stereo input (line level.)  Make sure to select "line" as your source, and use both channels.  Line level requires a higher signal level than microphone, though.  [You might need an input buffer and amplifier.](http://xoscope.sourceforge.net/hardware/hardware.html)

Comment: You need two channels (line in) and XY mode to try to see the double scroll.  I don't think it will show up especially well.  It does depend on how fast it flips between the two main centers, though.

Comment: @JRE It is clearly oscillating.

Comment: @JRE Thank you for telling me about "line".

Comment: The Chua does not play interesting sounds, just scatter plots. http://tinyurl.com/y2ro73ag  The R ratios are critical.  THe right mouse in menu under circuits, Op Amps at bottom, Chaotic circuits will have more interesting ones..  There is also undo ^z and file last saved.  Search me for other related answers

Comment: @Jethro:  Ok. Cool.  Could you post an answer (use line in, XY mode, anything else it took to make it work) and pictures of the output.

Comment: YOu dont have enough points to show the curves  Try this http://tinyurl.com/y2g84l6w or that http://tinyurl.com/yxfdeyex

Comment: @JRE Could you recommand some cheap sound cards that support line input?

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 Could you make it show sinudial wave patten (volts against time) as well? I don't know how.

Comment: I pointed to the 3 outputs each then Show In Scope > then point and right Mouse Stack each, then Properties and adjust slider to right for faster sweep. then I repeated for 3 scope traces unlocked near schematic then drag to reposition and leave each as a slow sweep. http://tinyurl.com/y23kwpqd

Comment: just about every obsolete PC had line or AUX input. on the motherboard